# Manipular dados do Firebase no controller com angular 1

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Estou trabalhando com Angular 1, angularfire e Firebase.
Fiz a seguinte chamada que me retorna os dados a seguir:

```
var _refLista = firebase.database().ref()
$scope.lista = $firebaseObject(_refLista.child('listas').child(idLista))
console.log($scope.lista);
```

No console os dados aparecem estruturados da seguinte forma:

```
{
    nome: "nome da lista",
    usuarios: [0:"OkJiuyhTfrdgF", 1:"kjIugYHTkiuh"]
}
```

Na view consigo imprimir tudo certindo, exemplo:

```
{{ lista.nome }}
{{ lista.usuarios }}
```

Mas quando tento acessar $scope.lista.usuarios no controller o resultado é sempre undefined.

Alguem pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você carregou um objeto a partir do "$firebaseObjec" ele retorna um objeto JavaScript que contém os dados do Firebase
com alguns campos adicionais e específicos do AngularFire, este objeto pode não estar disponível completamente por causa do carregamento assíncrono, use a função $loaded() para carregar o objeto exemplo:

```
   $scope.lista = $firebaseObject(_refLista.child('listas').child(idLista))
   $scope.lista.$loaded().then(function (res) {           
       //AQUI VOCÊ PODE LER AS PROPRIEDADES
       console.log("Minha lista",lista.usuarios)             
   })
```

Comment: Obrigado. Resolveu.